# How do I balance a campaign consisting of four kobold PCs?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, balance, racial-traits, kobold

I am currently planning a campaign consisting of four kobold PCs, using *Volo's Guide to Monsters* (p. 119) as my starting point for the race.

However, I am worried about Pack Tactics and Sunlight Sensitivity.

> **Pack Tactics.** You have advantage on an attack roll against a creature if at least one of your allies is within 5 feet of the creature and the ally isn't incapacitated.
>
> **Sunlight Sensitivity.** You have disadvantage on attack rolls and Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight when you, the target of your attack, or whatever you are trying to perceive is in direct sunlight.

Kobolds as pictured in *Volo's Guide* seem very strong, gaining advantage on practically every attack roll. The inclusion of Sunlight Sensitivity does not, to me, seem like it's doing very much to make them weaker - in a typical combat scenario the worst it'll do is cancel out the advantage given by Pack Tactics, rather than ever realistically give disadvantage. Kobolds obviously favour fighting in the dark, so simply railroading every fight to be in the sunlight does not seem like it would be fun for me nor the players.

How would I bring down the power level of these kobolds to something more resembling that of PHB player races, while hopefully still keeping some kobold flavour?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] for further guidance.

Comment: @Overthinks Please see [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments) for why your comment was removed. You're welcome to ask us in chat for the content of that comment if you want to use it to post a proper answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### Don't nerf the players, buff the challenges

If the entire party consists of kobolds, there is no reason to decrease their power level. Simply adjust the encounters to be a suitable challenge for the group. You can find guidance for adjusting the power level of encounters in many places, but in my experience, every group will need tinkering individually to find the perfect blend of difficulty and fun.

I've done similar things for parties that started with a feat at 1st level. It can be a delicate balancing effort, but after a few combats you'll get an idea as to where they should be. I find that my players enjoy being able to utilize the strengths they've planned for while still having suitable challenges.

Answer (score 7):

[David's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148156/how-do-i-balance-a-campaign-consisting-of-four-kobold-pcs/148158#148158) is spot on.

I would say try to have some usual enemies the players can steamroll, and feel like they made the right choice choosing Kobolds.

Then introduce some challenging enemies with high AC so its challenging and also makes them feel like they are lucky to have Pack Tactics :)

Also some sunlit stuff where they have to use their brains would also be good now and then.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Have you used such methods in your own games? How have they worked in your experience?